# Drupal filters and $_GET arguments

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

**DRUPAL 6**

Hello everybody, can someone help me with this problem?

I have a carousel (view) called '**heat_model_carousel**' and this carousel displays a list of sauna's. SO, each sauna has a field called '**Model Type**' - which can be : Basic, Advanced or Premium.

Now, i added a block of links : `<a href = '?model_type=Basic'></a>`

I just want to filter these results on the model type so only in the carousel will appear Basic, Advanded or Premium Sauna's...

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In this view's setting, set a Filter for "Model Type," and then check the box that says "Expose this filter to visitors, to allow them to change it." This will generate a control right on the view that will allow users to filter by the Model Type.

Comment: Yes, but that did work, but, I need to be the exposed form to display as links. So I'm not using an exposed form, but a separate block with links to filter the main-view.

Comment: Try the [Better Exposed Filters](http://drupal.org/project/better_exposed_filters) module. I believe it gives you the ability to render the exposed form as links.

Answer (score 0):

In views add argument for "model type", Please pass your argument through url like

path-to-view-page/**Basic**

This will help you to filter " field Model Type = Basic"